# What does "activate base" do in MS Visual Studio code debug prompt?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I upgraded my anaconda and visual studio code bundle from python 3.6.5 to 3.7.1 and now when I run debug mode the debug prompt (and Conda Prompt) have this "(base)" prefix to the command line. What is this and what does it do? Can I get rid of it?

And now I can't run in debug mode properly. Should I just revert back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(base)` prefix indicates that you are in the base Anaconda environment.  It is the same as the standard command prompt, but has some added environmental variables set and some additional location prepended to the `PATH` variable.

To remove the prefix, you can configure conda to not show it via:

```
conda config --set changeps1 False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So then this has nothing to do with my debugger not working?

Comment: I doubt it.  You can ask another question and provide more details to what is going wrong.